# Is using Azure functions V1 queue triggered with Azure Managed Identity instead of connection strings possible?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-managed-identity, azure-durable-functions

All of the questions I found seems to check on functions v3, is using identity on connection to Azure storage queues on queue trigger and durable functions possible in Azure functions v1?

I couldnt find any official relevant docs that can help answer this question.

Comment: I would say no: I would assume the function v1 SDK is not compatible with these new features.

Comment: Hell @hossam, could you please update the question which identity it is like `Azure Managed Identity`!

Comment: What i mean is the trigger + bindings cant use managed identity with v1.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This [`Azure Managed Identity`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Identity) feature supports from Azure Functions v1 (.NET Framework Versions.

But I found one example from official documentation i.e.,

[Tutorial of Connecting to SQL Database from .NET App Service using a managed identity](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/app-service/tutorial-connect-msi-sql-database.md#tutorial-connect-to-sql-database-from-net-app-service-without-secrets-using-a-managed-identity).

This process/tutorial is covered for both .NET Framework 4.8 (v1 Azure Functions) and .NET Core (v2, v3, v4).

In this [GitHub Repo of Azure Managed Identity](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/app-service/overview-managed-identity.md), we have information for all the programming languages along with detailed explanations.

And there are few Questions in Stack Overflow related to issues coming in using the [Managed Identity in Azure Functions v1](https://www.google.com/search?q=azure%20functions%20.net%20framework%204.8%20with%20managed%20identity%20site:stackoverflow.com&newwindow=1&rlz=1C1VDKB_enIN982IN982&biw=1366&bih=649&sxsrf=ALiCzsa8Ct029SIg0KCZ9eHf5plwOt21kA:1652839963376&ei=G1aEYo7OFt_L2roP84OOgAs&oq=&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYBjIHCCMQ6gIQJzIHCCMQ6gIQJzIHCCMQ6gIQJzIHCCMQ6gIQJzIHCCMQ6gIQJzIHCCMQ6gIQJzIHCCMQ6gIQJzIHCCMQ6gIQJzIHCCMQ6gIQJzIHCCMQ6gIQJ0oECEEYAEoECEYYAFAAWABgp9UKaAJwAXgAgAEAiAEAkgEAmAEAoAEBsAEKwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz) (.NET Framework versions).

Comment: What I mean with Microsoft identity is the Azure managed identity (MSI) feature https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview,
Thanks for your answer and I apologize for the confusion.